# Issue with image slider showing above moving nav bar

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website where there is a nav bar that moves with the page scroll. 
I have an image slider in the right column that when I scroll down it appears above the nav bar.

I've been kicking my head as to why why it does this. Also the image in the slider doesn't fill it up...

I also have a footer that is supposed to stay at the bottom of the page but when I change it's height it moves. I have a margin set in the page wrap that I change when changing the footer height to try and mend this but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/4d57zxLj/)

```
           <div class="page-wrap">
           <header class="topbar topbar-blue">
            <div class="topbar-left">
            <div class="topbar-logo">
             <a href="/">
                <img class="mysite-logo" src="images/logo/logo2.png" alt="Mysite Logo" />
                <!-- MySite main log here -->
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
       <nav class="topbar-nav">
        <ul class="topbar-nav-main">
            <li id="home-nav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="design-nav"><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
            <li id="shop-nav"><a href="store.html">Shop</a></li>
            <li id="gallery-nav"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li id="about-nav"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
       <div class="topbar-right">
      <div class="hamburger"><img src="images/nav-icon.png"></div>
      <div class="hamburger2"><a href="login.html">Login</div>
      <div class="hamburger3"><img src="images/cart-icon.png"></div>
      </div>
      </nav>

    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the z-index in .topbar class.

```
.topbar {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
height: 100px;
font-size: 19px;
font-weight: 700;
z-index:1;      
}
```

For image,  remove width from `#slideshow-inner>ul>li`

```
#slideshow-inner>ul>li {
/*width: 20%;*/  /*Removed this*/
height: 320px;
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4d57zxLj/3/)**

Comment: Thank you! I'm kicking myself. I had that in my initial code too and deleted it thinking it was the problem for something else. Any thoughts on the footer issue?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the idea what you want to do with footer.? Do you want it to stay fixed in bottom?

Comment: Exactly.It seems that if I change the height of the footer to  adjust for new content it doesn't stay fixed to the bottom. I've adjusted footer height and margin in the page wrap with no luck.

Comment: Sorry, got busy.! have you sorted the footer issue.?

Comment: No problem at all :) eh kind of.  I got them aligned where I want them but it's still a bit off. I'm in work now. If I posted a fiddle later of what I got would you have a look? Also the slider doesn't seem to work properly again

Comment: Think it's the image size I'm using possibly?

Comment: Sure. Do let us know if any issue.! It will be great if you post a complete code as in previous one image links were broken in footer section.

Comment: Will do! I'll let you know when I'm back on layer. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi sorry I never got back on last night. Was later than I thought I would be when I got home.  So here's a link to my full fiddle. I'm getting this weird issue now when ever I move the mouse over anything that's not the header or footer it's as if I'm hovering over a link. I had a look for a div out of place but can't seem to find one. Any idea why it's happening? http://jsfiddle.net/TaliZorah/47nf1159/3/

Comment: Also notice the images in the viewer have a gap between them. I've tried changing the slide sizes in the css with no effect

Comment: It is good to post issues as a new questions. But still, `... it's as if I'm hovering over a link.` -> Solution: Your `<a href=''` tag is not closed. Close it `<div class="hamburger2"><a href="login.html">Login</a></div>` and the issue will be gone.

Comment: Thank you! I did post it as a new issue and figured that out, thanks though :). Have another one I'll post as a new question too :)